# Show more information on Gradle language elements in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

How can I get IntelliJ to show more documentation about Gradle language elements?

In the attached image, I'm using the Quick Documentation feature on Gradle's "compile" method name.

As you can see, other than the signature, there's no further information, requiring me to visit https://docs.gradle.org to dig deeper.

[image]